# Cannot break Shrek loop in Rstudio

Tags: r, loops, while-loop, break

I have created a "while" loop that looks like this:

```
x <- 2
while (x < 8) {
    print("Shrek") 
}
```

Now, I have tried breaking the loop by inserting break in to the while loop, like this:

```
while (x < 8) {
    print("Shrek")
    break
}
```

but this doesn't break the loop, the console just keeps printing "Shrek".
How can i make it stop? Have I put break in the wrong place?

Side question: Can there arise any problems from exiting Rstudio while it's in an on-going while() loop like this?

Thanks!

Edit:
Pressing escape stopped the loop. Is there any line of code in the console that also stops it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code you have given I can't reproduce this. When I run everything, break works just fine. Have you potentially defined a variable called 'break' that would have overridden the default function? If not try resetting R and running this again.